# Get value from one class and add text to all with the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I may have two or more classes with the same name.
After user click in one button, I would like to count + 1 to a counter that I have. So I tried:

```
var likes_count = parseInt($('.likes_count'+I).first().text()) + 1;

$('.likes_count'+I).first().text(likes_count);
```

with first, it will change only the first elemente value after click, adding +1 on it, but the second and so one will not change. If I remove first the counter will go crazy.

How to change all of them? adding +1 on classes with the same name?

Comment: Show related markup and explain what is `I`

Comment: `I` is a number, an id to the counter class, to know each class I will count + 1.

Comment: I can't use `this` because user will click in one button, and the counter is on another one.

Answer (score 2):

I commented the code explaining my approach, hope it helps

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  //get class index by splitting on 'likes_count'
  var classIndex = $(this).attr('class').split('likes_count')[1];
    
  var likes_count = parseInt($('.likes_count'+classIndex).first().text()) + 1;

//you were close, just apply pass function to each .text() like so:
$('.likes_count'+classIndex).text(function(){
  return likes_count;
});
});
```

```css
.likes_count1{
  background: red
}
.likes_count2{
  background: green
}
.likes_count3{
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="likes_count1">0</button>
<button class="likes_count1">0</button>
<button class="likes_count2">0</button>
<button class="likes_count3">0</button>
<button class="likes_count3">0</button>
<button class="likes_count2">0</button>
<button class="likes_count2">0</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
$(".likes_count").each(function() {
     $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text()) + 1);
 });
```

Example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".likes_count").each(function() {
       $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text()) + 1);
     });
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="likes_count">3</div>
<div class="likes_count">5</div>
<div class="likes_count">7</div>

<button type="button">Increment</button>
```